# Как выполнить цикл в подзапросе MSSQL

Tags: sql

Подскажите, как правильно реализовать такое?
Есть таблица:

| OwnerId | objId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 2 | 46 |
| 3 | 33 |

Т.е. в одной таблице хранятся данные, которые имеют как бы координаты в каком порядке им отображаться, objId может быть ownerId для другого элемента таблицы.
Получается в виде вот такого:

> - 1
>
>   - 2
>
>     - 25
>
>       46
>
>     3
>
>     - 33

Я делал селект к самому минимальному значению ownerID - получал это значение, и потом в цикле перебирал и выводил все значения "where OwnerId = полученному objID", т.е. что-то вроде вывода древа элементов с дочерними элементами код на php получился очень громоздким. Можно ли как-то сделать данную процедуру средствами SQL?

Comment: Обычное дерево. Рекурсивный CTE в помощь. Сортировать по полному пути узла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример для MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE test (OwnerId INT, objId INT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 25),
(2, 46),
(3, 33);
```

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, path, level) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         OwnerId, CAST(OwnerId AS CHAR(65535)), 0
  FROM test t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM test t2
    WHERE t1.OwnerId = t2.objId
    )
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT test.objId, CONCAT_WS('.', cte.path, test.objId), cte.level + 1
  FROM cte
  JOIN test ON cte.id = test.OwnerId
  )
SELECT CONCAT(REPEAT('...', level), id) node -- выпендрёж, конечно...
-- SELECT id node
FROM cte
ORDER BY path
```

| node |
| --- |
| 1 |
| ...2 |
| ......25 |
| ......46 |
| ...3 |
| ......33 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qND4e5ue)